# python docxtpl insert two sub documents into one template

Tags: python, docxtpl

I would like to insert two generated sub documents into one template. It partly works, but it seems that there is a bug in docxtpl. The end of my template disappears if I insert my sub document(s).
See the following example:

The template.docx has the following content:

```
some text

{{p subdoc1}}

again some text

{{p subdoc2}}

and at the end of the document also some text
```

My sample code is:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("docx_template.docx")

sd1 = doc.new_subdoc()
sd1.add_paragraph("First subdoc")

sd2 = doc.new_subdoc()
sd2.add_paragraph("Second subdoc")

context = {"subdoc1" : sd1, "subdoc2" : sd2}

doc.render(context)
doc.save("output.docx")
```

What I expect in output.docx is:

```
some text

First subdoc

again some text

Second subdoc

and at the end of the document also some text
```

What I get is:

```
some text

First subdoc
```

the second sub document and the end of the documents text is not in the saved output.docx.

What am I doing wrong? 
I also run the test subdoc.py from
https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/tree/master/tests.
The end of the generated document also disappears. I'm not sure if this is a wanted feature or maybe a bug.

My versions are:

- python 3.9.12
- docxtpl checked with 0.11.5 and 0.16.4 (same behaviour)
- python-docx  0.8.11

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same project that you posted and I am able to get the desired result.

My used versions are:

- Python - 3.11.1
- docxtpl - 0.16.6
- python-docx - 0.8.11

Can you try with **docxtpl version 0.16.6** and see any difference.

Comment: with version 0.16.6 it works